# Ruby on Rails displaying an embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey this is probably a very simple question but I can't seem to get my show.html.erb page to display and I am a real beginner.  This is made in ruby on rails.  Here is my code:

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist
  has_many :songs
end
```

**Song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lyric, :name, :song_id
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**CreatePost Migrate**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :artist
      t.string :song

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**CreateSong Migrate**

```
class CreateSongs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :songs do |t|
      t.text :lyric
      t.string :name
      t.integer :song_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<center><h1><%= @post %></h1></center>
<p> Songs: </p>
<% @post.song.song_id.each do |s| %>
    <p>
        <%= s.name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<% form_for [@post, Song.new] do |f| %>
  <p>

    <%= f.label :name, "Artist" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
    <%= f.label :body, "Song Name:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add Song" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the controller.

Controllers in Ruby on Rails marshall data between the models and the view.

I suggest you probably want to create a controller in the app/controllers folder like:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

You also need to ensure that the posts resource is setup in the routes file.

In the config/routes.rb file you can put

```
resources :posts
```

This tells Rails that the /posts url refers to the posts controller.

Getting started with RoR can be a bit tricky with all the various moving parts.  I highly recommend [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com) for short tutorial snippets.  Also [peepcode.com](http://peepcode.com) for more indepth instructions.